# Web Page Not Reloading

Tags: python, html

I am executing the following code.

```
import webapp2

form="""
    <form method = "post">
    What is your birthday?
    <p>
    <label>
    Day
    <input type = "text" name = "day">
    Month
    <input type = "text" name = "month">
    Year
    <input type = "text" name = "year">
    </p>
    <input type = "submit">
    </form>
    """

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
    self.response.out.write(form)

    def post(self):
    self.response.out.write(form)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

When I try opening the page **localhost:8080**, I do not see anything. The page is empty.

Comment: What is serving the web page? [This page](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/tutorials/quickstart.html) suggests either Google App engine or a local setting should do that. Have you set either of those up?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with webapp2 but:

after a quick look to [tutorials](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/tutorials/quickstart.html) I have seen them write:

```
self.response.write(...) instead of self.response.out.write()
```

your code is not correctly indented, you should have:

```
   def get(self):
       self.response.write(form)
```

the string "form" does not seem like a valid html page

maybe you could try

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Whatever</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method = "post">
    What is your birthday?
    <p>
    <label>
    Day
    <input type = "text" name = "day">
    Month
    <input type = "text" name = "month">
    Year
    <input type = "text" name = "year">
    </p>
    <input type = "submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```